# pytorch: Why is Dataloader loaded dimensionally？

Tags: python, pytorch, dataloader

```
img_path = 'G:/tiff/NC_H08_20220419_0600.tif'
img = io.imread(img_path).astype(np.float32)
print(img.shape)
data_tf = torchvision.transforms.Compose([torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()])
train_data = data_tf(img)
print(train_data.shape)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_data, batch_size=1)
print(len(train_loader))
```

result:

```
(2486, 2755, 16)
torch.Size([16, 2486, 2755])
16
```

I think `len(train_loader)` is 1，but now it is 16, I wonder why.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataLoader` assumes you pass in a dataset, which is usually not a single piece of data. Therefore, it will interpret the first dimension usually as the batch dimension. So, in your case, it assumes you have 16 pieces of 2D data.

To solve it, add a batch dimension to your `train_data`. (Or make a [`Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html), but that seems like a hassle for your simple use case)

Comment: I don't have much data at the moment, but I'm still collecting it. Can I just make a dataset to solve this problem

Comment: Look at the docs I linked above and for example this tutorial: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html.